# Create a list of clickable nodes (web elements) in Codeception test (webdriver)

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, codeception

I am using the WebDriver module in Codeception acceptance tests.

In a test I need to create a list of nodes (web elements) from a web page and click each node in a `foreach` loop. Nodes are main navigation menu items. See screen shot.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of4o8.png)

I've tried to use a built-in method called `grabMultiple("//nav[@class='nav-container']/ul/li/a")` but it returns a list of names ("Ready to Wear", etc.) and the `click` method can't click such elements of this list.

Is there any way in Codeception to create a list of nodes which are clickable?

When I use following code:

```
$itemsOfMainNav = $I->grabMultiple("//nav[@class='nav-container']/ul/li/a");

foreach($itemsOfMainNav as $item){
    $I->click($item);
}
```

I'm getting error:

1) Failed to check main categories are reachable  in 101_CategoryFlowCept (tests\acceptance\101_CategoryFlowCept.php)

Step  I click "READY TO WEAR"
 Fail  Link or Button or CSS or XPath element with 'READY TO WEAR' was not found.

Scenario Steps:

6. $I->click("READY TO WEAR")
7. $I->grabMultiple("//nav[@class='nav-container']/ul/li/a")
8. $I->wait(1)

Comment: whats the issue here? This will give you a list of elements with `anchor` tag right? What exactly are you looking for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After suggestion of Naktibalda I've created following code and it works for me:

```
$mainNavLinks = $I->grabMultiple("//nav[@class='nav-container']/ul/li/a", 'href'); 
foreach ($mainNavLinks as $link) { 
    $I->amOnUrl($link); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could grab class attributes and use them for clicking.

```
$linkClasses = $I->grabMultiple("//nav[@class='nav-container']/ul/li/a", 'class');
foreach ($linkClasses as $linkClass) {
  $I->click(['class' => $linkClass]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!

I've used following code: 

`$mainNavLinks = $I->grabMultiple("//nav[@class='nav-container']/ul/li/a", 'href');
foreach ($mainNavLinks as $link) {
  $I->amOnUrl($link);
}`